# border-image url not working

Tags: css

I'm having a really odd problem with image borders. I am working on a MacBook Pro, 10.6.8, with the most recent browsers I can install on it.  I have a navigation list using image borders, so:

```
    #navlist li 
    {   border:solid; 
        border-width: 1px 0 1px 19px; 
        -webkit-border-image:url("imgs/borderimage-nonleft-mid.png") 1 0 1 19  fill repeat stretch;
        border-image:url("imgs/borderimage-nonleft-mid.png") 1 0 1 19 fill repeat stretch;
        background: #ce0c6a;
        padding:0.5em 2em;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

This works fine in Safari(5.1), Firefox(33), and Chrome(38). Then I have a style for the selected item, nearly identical but with a different url:

```
    #navlist li.selected    
    {   -webkit-border-image:url("imgs/borderimage-select-mid.png") 1 19 fill repeat stretch;
        border-image:url("imgs/borderimage-select-mid.png") 1 19 fill repeat stretch;
        border-image-outset: 0 0 1px 0;
        border:solid; 
        border-width:1px 19px;
        border-image-width:1px 19px;
        background: #0fe8b5;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

This works fine in Safari. Both Firefox and Chrome insist the computed url is 'none'. I have scoured the W3C specs, searched stack exchange, googled my fingers off. I simply can't find a reason for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

cct

Comment: You may want to play with such tool http://border-image.com and try to achieve your expected result there in Chrome/FF

Comment: try to use this without "border:solid"

Comment: @FrederikWitte Thank you, that did it! I would love to understand why, though, when all the answers I came up with in my hunt swore the border style had to be set? #confused! Can you make the comment an answer so I can set it?

Comment: And I'm really confused over why it worked in #navlist li, which had border:solid set??

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: For your info, when you use only border, the only required value is the style, eg "solid, dashed, etc". Other values like the width and color are optional. So that is probably what they meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you explanation, the debugger rolls over your css from top to bottom, things at the top are rendered first, then stuff at the bottom. In your first class, you have `border: solid;` at top(which will just create a normal border), but you have a `border-image` below it, which will overwrite the `border` property. This is why, your image is being displayed perfectly.

In your second class, it is the other way around. You overwrite your `border-image` by using `border:solid;`, because it's standing below the `border-image`.

You can also leave out the "border-width".

```
#navlist li.selected    
    {   -webkit-border-image:url("imgs/borderimage-select-mid.png") 1 19 fill repeat stretch;
        border-image:url("imgs/borderimage-select-mid.png") 1 19 fill repeat stretch;
        border-image-outset: 0 0 1px 0;
        border-image-width:1px 19px;
        background: #0fe8b5;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

This will work just fine.